# How to create symbolic polynomial using coefficient vector and symbolic variable vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix-multiplication, symbolic-math

I have a coefficient column vector looking something like

```
x = [1 2 3]'
```

that aligns with the polynomial p(z) = x_0 + x_1*z + x_2*z^2 + ... + x_n-1*z^(n-1). My question is, how would one create a symbolic vector using MATLAB, something like

```
p = [1 z z^2]
```

so that when I take the matrix product

```
p*x
```

and print it I get a 1x1 "matrix" of the expression `1 + 2z + 3z^2`?

Furthermore, how can I generalize the creation of p to extend for arbitrary powers z^3, z^4, ...?

Thanks!

Comment: You might not need symbolic stuff here at all. Take a look at [`polyval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html), I think it does just what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = z.^(0:2);
```

In general:

```
p = z.^(0:n-1);
```

where `n` equals number of elements.